# No action after triggering jenkins job using bitbucket-hook

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I'm trying to trigger a job using bitbucket-hook. I don't see anything in jenkins log but inspecting the network traffic I found the response from jenkins to bitbucket:

```
T 12.34.56.78:8080 -> 131.103.20.165:36292 [AP]
HTTP/1.1 302 Found..X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff..Location: http://myserver:8080/bitbucket-hook/..Content-Length: 0..Server: Jetty(winstone-2.8)....
```

Any idea what can I check, test or do?

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Nop. I'm setting bamboo currently

Answer (score 0):

You may like to double-check the case of the letters you are using to configure the Jenkins/CI URL in Bitbucket.

Remember the web-hook is case-sensitive.

Comment: Wonder what caused you to down-vote the answer. I had the same issue, struggled with it for a long time and managed to resolve it after fixing the case of the URL. Just because the answer didn't help your case, doesnt mean its not-useful.